# Adventnet library for snmp v3 traps

Tags: snmp

I am having a hard time to decrypt snmp v3 messages using adventnet library whereas snmp4j works just great. I have tried all the examples from adventnet site but none of them seems to work for v3. Can someone help me out plz ?

Comment: Contact the vendor of the library.

Comment: did managed to get v3 traps using adventnet?